# ArcGIS API for Silverlight - pass geometries to ESRI service

Tags: c#, geometry, arcgis-silverlight-api

How would I test this service to find what it wants?  http://sampleserver4.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Elevation/ESRI_Elevation_World/MapServer/exts/ElevationsSOE/ElevationLayers/1/GetElevations

It says geometries.  But does it want a polyline or a point.  I tried just putting a lat/long in the dialog box but no go.

What I have is a result from a densify service

```
void DensifyService_DensifyCompleted(object sender, GraphicsEventArgs e)
    {
        GraphicsLayer graphicsLayerVertices = MyMap.Layers["VerticesGraphicsLayer"] as GraphicsLayer;
        foreach (Graphic graphic in e.Results)
        {
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Polyline p = graphic.Geometry as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Polyline;


            foreach (ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.PointCollection pc in (graphic.Geometry as Polyline).Paths)
            {
                foreach (MapPoint point in pc)
                {
                    Graphic vertice = new Graphic()
                    {
                        Symbol = LayoutRoot.Resources["DefaultMarkerSymbol"] as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.Symbol,
                        Geometry = point
                    };
                    graphicsLayerVertices.Graphics.Add(vertice);
                }
            }

        }
        DensifyButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

So what I am wanting to do is get each MapPoint geometries from the 
    foreach (MapPoint point in pc)

And figure out how to get that into a list or whatever format is needed by the elevation service at the top of the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this blog post and the sample included in the SOE source code?  They got me on the right track

http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/apl/archive/2010/10/07/Elevation-Server-Object-Extension.aspx

http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/arcobjects-net-api/details?entryID=87BEC705-1422-2418-34B5-308930DE323A

A typical string that I am passing from my app is: 
GetElevationData?Extent={"spatialReference":{"wkid":2246},"xmax":1202184.46609375,"xmin":1194752.28390625,"ymax":248223.36453125,"ymin":240791.18234375}&Rows=51&Columns=51&f=json

Comment: +1 Too bad Esri doesn't provide a method to publish metadata for a GP service that would reveal this sort of thing. Instead, it's buried in a word document in the sample download.

Comment: So if I append this string "?lon=-95.380854&lat=29.754591&json" to the end of the GetElevationAtLonLat, I get a returned elevation.  But I can't figure out what format I need to pass the geometry to the GetElevations url.  Any thoughs?  Thanks.